# R: Cross check a text document with a set of data frame/dictionary of words

Tags: r, dictionary, text, classification

new to R and coding here and i'm still a student. I have a text document and wanted to do a crosscheck with set of dictionary/df that i already clean and tokenize the document into its root word. The objective is to crosscheck Document1 with dictionary1 to see if there is any word in document1 match with word in dictionary. And if yes, the document will be tag according to its class. The example will be like this:

```
Document1 <- "One simple text"
dictionary1 <- data.frame("Term"= c("teacher", "simple", "shoot", "text"))

if (strcmp(Document1, dictionary1)){
print('Success')
} else {
print('Failed')
}
```

the result that I have tried with this code will printed out as "Failed", even though there is a word "simple" and "text" that matched in Document1. How do i solve this? Am I need to do **strsplit** on document1 first, then do comparisons using **strcmp** function? Thanks in advance whoever that can provide solution for this. Apologize on my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO, we can program most things inside a data.frame in r

```r
library(tidyverse)

Document1 <- "One simple text"
dictionary1 <- data.frame("Term" = c("teacher", "simple", "shoot", "text"))


df_results <- dictionary1 %>%
  mutate(result = str_detect(string = Document1, pattern = Term))

df_results
#>      Term result
#> 1 teacher  FALSE
#> 2  simple   TRUE
#> 3   shoot  FALSE
#> 4    text   TRUE


if (any(df_results$result == TRUE)) {
  print("Sucess")
} else {
  print("Failure")
}
#> [1] "Sucess"

Document1 <- "Nothing Matters"
dictionary1 <- data.frame("Term" = c("teacher", "simple", "shoot", "text"))


df_results <- dictionary1 %>%
  mutate(result = str_detect(string = Document1, pattern = Term))

df_results
#>      Term result
#> 1 teacher  FALSE
#> 2  simple  FALSE
#> 3   shoot  FALSE
#> 4    text  FALSE


if (any(df_results$result == TRUE)) {
  print("Sucess")
} else {
  print("Failure")
}
#> [1] "Failure"

# Another way is using vectors

Document1 <- "simple right"
dictionary1 <- data.frame("Term" = c("teacher", "simple", "shoot", "text"))

result <- str_detect(string = Document1, pattern = dictionary1$Term)

result
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

if (any(result == TRUE)) {
  print("Sucess")
} else {
  print("Failure")
}
#> [1] "Sucess"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: woahh, great! Thank you so much Bruno for this answer and example. This help me a lot for my research! Thanks again for answered my question.

Comment: No problem please consider voting as well